# How to parse iOS receipt file locally in Unity3d?

Tags: ios, parsing, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, receipt

I have a path to a receipt file on the device.

Do you guys have an idea how i can convert this file to smth readable to get, say, the date of the latest in-app purchase (using C# in Unity3d)?

[The receipt i'm talking about](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateLocally.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010573-CH1-SW2)

Comment: Nope. I'm waiting for Unity 5.3 release. Maybe built-in Unity in-app purchases support will provide full access to the receipt.
The only other way i found wass to use plugins on the asset store that provide access to almost all native iOS classes.
Like this https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/9555
But i didn't like user reviews on the asset.

Comment: @ViatcheslavTarasov fortunately this is now fully built-in to Unity, notice links here .. http://stackoverflow.com/q/36167767/294884