# Where the heck is Unity's CrossPlatformValidator?

Tags: unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to use Unity's excellent new `CrossPlatformValidator`

(Such as seen ...
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityIAPValidatingReceipts.html or
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dJzeoGPeUIUetvFCulsvRz1TwRNOcJzwTDVf23gk8Rg)

But it can't be found!  Naturally I am ...

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Purchasing;
```

I also tried different stripping and .Net levels. Nothing.

Anyone have a clue about this?

> The type or namespace name `CrossPlatformValidator' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: I can't find it anywhere in the Unity libraries either: https://docs.unity3d.com/410/Documentation/ScriptReference/30_search.html?q=CrossPlatformValidator Maybe its an un-referenced asset from the Unity Asset Store or something ?

Comment: Hi Zze .. the fact that Unity "forgot to put something in the documentation" is just a basic thing in the industry.  Like for a few years nobody has even bothered making fun about it. It would be better if they just clicked delete on all their doco and stopped pretending  :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Stuff like this is usually **found** at `UnityEngine.Experimental` but it wasn't there when I looked so I guess it is **not** a new feature.

**1.** You can **find** it by going to **Windows** **->** **Services**. **Sign** in on the **Window displayed**, usually on the right.

**2.** **Create** a **Project ID** on that Window.

**3.** Click on **In-APP Purchasing**. It is checked to **OFF**, click on it then click **Enable**.

**Note**: You must **Sign** in to be able to **Enable** it and you must **Enable** it **before** you can **use** it from **Script**.

---

Finally, the completely undocumented namespace is:

## using UnityEngine.Purchasing.Security;

note that one can see this in the generated "tangle" files, for example, if one forgets it. :/

Comment: Ah - great point you have to have it turned on, thanks.  And, I finally dug up the frickin' namespace...

Comment: Wait...You were able to use that namespace without enabling the AIP or did you have to enable AIP before using it? Where is the "tangle" files ? I want to know...

Comment: To be clear, in the project we had already (of course) enabled Services/Analytics/IAP and clicked to install all the stuff you need to do that like months ago, you know.  It is true that I had accidentally turned off the services: however (in fact) it does "leave in" all the libraries if you happen to turn it off (obvious in retrospect, or of course you'd get millions of errors immediately).  Now, the tangle files are reasonably well explained in here https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dJzeoGPeUIUetvFCulsvRz1TwRNOcJzwTDVf23gk8Rg/edit .. just click to create one and you'll see it!

Comment: Bottom line is I didn't know about the `.Security` namespace - once you find it it works!  Fortunately it will never again be a problem since this post is now on the internet  :)  Go [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-iap-store-guides-google-play-apple-app-store-windows-store.372647/page-3#post-2565610) to save typing out a codebase to use Unity's absolutely fantastic (this is from a guy who usually describes everything they do as "crapola") new IAP.

Comment: Oh I see. I have only used this once and wanted to know if it is possible to use it again without network/Signing in. Thanks for that link

Comment: **It does appear that it works fine if you are not signed-in.**  (Which is confusing!)  Regarding literally having no network on your laptop while developing ... I've found it's (not unreasonably) just more and more difficult to use Unity these days unless you have a live connection.  (On the rare occasions Unity's cloud is flakey, it's a real PITA.)  You probably have the same experience.  It is just so "connected" these days, there are so many services, licenses, libraries, it's pretty difficult to work with Unity, unless, you have a (good) net connection up -- my feeling on the matter.  :O

Comment: Yeah that's why I asked. I think they are doing it so that pirates wont be able to use some features in their software but that effects people with licence too. I had to sign in(once) to be able to generate that namespace and after that you dont have to do it again...

Comment: Right.  Note too that, you simply can't use Analytics (and hence, IAP, which (somewhat confusingly) is inherently part of Analytics), unless of course you have an Analytics account.  (So, similarly obviously you can't use Twitter, Facebook or YoruBank unless of course you have an account with those online services.)  So yeah you can't have *any access at all*, it seems, to Analytics (/IAP) until you literally have a Unity Services account. {Which seems different from your everyday "Unity account" where you can swear on the forum, etc.} As far as I can make out...

Comment: @Fattie curious what your final solution to IAP Subscriptions is

Answer (score 1):

Mono Dev can often help you find things.

Right click on unresolved class -> Resolve

Screenshot of resolve function in Mono Dev.:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Available in ***Unity​Engine.​Purchasing.​Security***